# Preserve Created and Modified date properties when dragging attachments out of Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How can I retain the created and modified date properties of a document which is attached to an email when saving/moving/dragging it into a drive on a windows machine?

I searched around and there are a lot of questions regarding how to move files without changing the properties.  I use FreeCommander for file management and I can click and drag files from one location to another without changing any properties.

*Moving files while retaining properties once they're in my file mgt system is no problem.*

Getting the files out of Outlook without resetting the clock for both the created and modified date is the problem.

I've looked around and tried to;

> drag into an external drive first, but windows rewrote the dates,
>
> zip the files, but I can't (or didn't figure out how to) do this from within an email,
>
> use Robocopy, but pointing that to an individual attachment in an Outlook appdata file is more involved than is practical since it would take less time to rewrite the properties after I've moved them (which is what I do now).
>
> drag the entire email into a folder before pulling the attachment, but windows reset the clock anyway.

Comment: Here is how Outlook behave: Outlook has always been weird with this - recent attachments would be saved with the saved date (received within the last 2-3 weeks), but attachments on older messages used the file's date. And I'm afraid there is no way to change this.

Comment: @Aidan, I don't understand what you mean by 'file date' and 'saved date'. Are you saying that Outlook uses two methods depending on the age of the email?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and I have to be careful every time when I open an old email, which had been saved in my explorer folders, to close it with a "NO" response to the dialog box question regarding the saving of my changes to the email (which is actually none since I only read the email).  Sometimes I miss and inadvertently click "YES" and the modified date is reset to the present date.  It is a pain since I use the modified date a lot of times for a quick access to an email that I don't recall its title.